# P.adj in TukeyHSD and HSD.test function can't be changed

Tags: r, tukey

Hi i was looking inside tukeyHSD and HSD.test the p.adj, i would like to get the p.value without adjustement. I tried to set an argument inside like:

or other things but nothing work at all. Package: agricolae.

```
TukeyHSD(x, p.adjust="none")
```

Comment: Tukey HSD without adjusting the p-value does not make much sense when having a multiple comparison problem. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253588/interpreting-tukeyhsd-output-in-r and the links in the answer to find out why.

Comment: How to change to another correction like Holm?